# Обработка коллизий двух разных объектов одним скриптом

Tags: c#, unity3d, коллизии

Есть два объекта с одинаковым кусочком кода, который я хотела бы загнать в один отдельный скрипт. Мне необходимо сделать, чтоб при столкновении двух объектов убывала переменная health нужного объекта, но у меня не получается

скрипт №1

```
public class AsteroidBig : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform asteroidMed;
    public float speed = 1.5f;
    public int health = 10;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D theCollision){
        if(theCollision.gameObject.name.Contains("laser")){
            Laser laser = theCollision.gameObject.GetComponent("Laser") as Laser;
            health -= laser.damage;
            Destroy (theCollision.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);       
        if (health <= 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Instantiate (asteroidMed, this.transform.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, Random.Range (0f, 360f)));
                Instantiate (asteroidMed, this.transform.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, Random.Range (0f, 360f)));
                Instantiate (asteroidMed, this.transform.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, Random.Range (0f, 360f)));
            }
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

скрипт №2

```
public class AsteroidMedium : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 1f;
    public int health = 4;
    public float TimeImmortal = 3f;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D theCollision){
        if(theCollision.gameObject.name.Contains("laser")){
            Laser laser = theCollision.gameObject.GetComponent("Laser") as Laser;
            health -= laser.damage;
            Destroy (theCollision.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);       
        if (health <= 0){
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Кусочек кода, который я пыталась загнать в отдельный скрипт

```
public class Stalk : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D theCollision){

        if(theCollision.gameObject.name.Contains("laser")){
            Laser laser = theCollision.gameObject.GetComponent("Laser") as Laser;
            health -= laser.damage;
            Destroy (theCollision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Скрипт лазера

```
public class Laser : MonoBehaviour {

    public float lifetime = 2.0f;
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public int damage = 1;

    void Start () {
        Destroy (gameObject, lifetime);
    }

    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт №0

```
public enum kAsteroidType { Big, Medium }

public class Asteroid : MonoBehaviour {
    public kAsteroidType aType; // <-----
    public Transform asteroidMed;
    public float speed;
    public int health;
    public float TimeImmortal;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D theCollision) {
        if (theCollision.gameObject.name.Contains("laser")) {
            Laser laser = theCollision.gameObject.GetComponent("Laser") as Laser;
            health -= laser.damage;
            Destroy(theCollision.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up*Time.deltaTime*speed);       
        if (health <= 0) {
            if (aType == kAsteroidType.Big) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    Instantiate(asteroidMed, this.transform.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0f, 360f)));
                    Instantiate(asteroidMed, this.transform.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0f, 360f)));
                    Instantiate(asteroidMed, this.transform.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0f, 360f)));
                }
            }
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Если атрибуты не указываются в префабе, то в коде так

```
void Start () {
    switch (aType) {
        case kAsteroidType.Big: {
            speed = 1.5f;
            health = 10f;
        } break;
        case kAsteroidType.Medium: {
            speed = 1f;
            health = 4f;
            TimeImmortal = 3f;
        } break;
    }
}
```